# Array Offset C++ pthreads return

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am running the following code in C++.

It runs as expected, however, the first result is NULL in the second for loop...however, every ensuing result is correct.

```
    pthread_t pthread_t_array[thread_count];
    int ireturn[thread_count];
    float chunk_elements[thread_count];

    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
    {
        float vector_chunk[3] = {2.0,4.0,3.0};

        pthread_t x;
        pthread_t_array[i] = x;

        ireturn[i] = pthread_create(&x,NULL,worker,(void *) vector_chunk);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
    {
        void * result;
        ireturn[i] = pthread_join(pthread_t_array[i],&result);


        // THE LINES BELOW: AT i = 0, result = NULL
        // however, at every other value of i, 14 is returned as expected. 

        if (result != NULL){
            chunk_elements[i] = *(float *) result;
        }
        free(result);
    }
```

The full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/RVUgEPeE).

I am not sure why there would be an array offset (at the line where I am testing if result is NULL--at i = 0, the result is NULL, but for every other i, it is not).  It seems like everything is going correctly.

**correction: it is not actually an offset, but rather, the first value is NULL, so there is one less value.**

Comment: You can't join `pthread_t_array[i]` since it's not a valid `pthread_t`. (You stored that in the (unnecessary) variable `x`, not in the array.)

Comment: @molbdnilo don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If, as it seems likely, the `worker()` thread, whose code is not shown, attempts to read the `vector_chunk` parameter that the thread receives, this is undefined behavior, and a bug.

This is because the `vector_chunk` array has automatic scope, and it exists only until the end of the for-loop iteration. As soon as `pthread_create()` returns, and its return value gets put into the array, the loop iteration ends, and the `vector_chunk` array goes out of scope, and is effectively destroyed.

There is no guarantee that the thread will execute and read `vector_chunk` before the parent thread reaches the end of its loop iteration, when the `vector_chunk` goes out of scope. Subsequent to `vector_chunk` going out of scope, any attempt by the `worker()` to access the `vector_chunk` parameter is undefined behavior, and a bug.

The solution is to dynamically allocate the parameter to the thread, initialize, and then start the thread, passing to its the dynamically-allocated parameter, with all the thread parameter data. The thread is responsible for retrieving its parameter data, and the deallocated its parameter.

Comment: ok, so...how would I make it work incorrectly (for now)--changing the location of vector chunk to the max scope in the main method does not fix..

Comment: There is insufficient information to answer that question. All questions on stackoverflow.com must include a [mcve] in the question itself. Links to external sites, that can stop working at any time, are insufficient.